# How to force flush DNS server in Windows Server 2012

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

The address of our company www has been changed from IP.OLD to IP.NEW some 10 days ago.
All public DNS servers incl. that of our ISP do reflect this change.

Our DNS server running at Windows Server 2012 stubbornly translates to IP.OLD.

Here are all steps I tried:

- ipconfig /flushdns (at server)
- DNS Manager - Action - Clear Cache / Update Server Data Files / Scavenge Stale Resource Records... Restart
- Properties - Forwarders: change their order, restart DNS... (Note: There are two of them, both translate to IP.NEW correctly.)
- Checked there are no Conditional Forwarders etc.

Is there any way to force this DNS server to translate the address to IP.NEW?

Comment: If you already flushed your DNS server's cache, the issue is likely with your forwarders. Try removing them and relying on root hints instead, then see what your local DNS server resolves it to.

Comment: @ThatGraemeGuy: I did as you suggested (removed both forwarders, flush, restart...) and still IP.OLD. I also tried to uncheck "Use root hints if no forwarders are available" as another attempt and again, nothing changed. There is no problem with those forwarders. If I set them as DNS server in a workstation, they translate to IP.NEW.

Comment: Note: Adding a record to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts to translate to IP.NEW helps for the server machine itself, not for its DNS functionality, so it's no workaround.

Comment: is your local DNS server authoritative for your domain?

Comment: @dusan.bajic: I've read some definitions what does "authoritative DNS server" mean and I'm not sure. We are rather a small company with only one domain and only one DNS server. There are two Forward Lookup Zones _msdcs.XXX.YY and XXX.YY in a DNS Manager tree, both running.

Comment: what is the output of `nslookup www.xxx.yy localhost` (run it on your DNS server), look for the `Address:...` line

Comment: and is XXX.YY the same as your public domain?  ie. is the query that gives the wrong IP querying for www.XXX.YY?

Comment: @dusan.bajic: `nslookup www.xxx.yy localhost`:
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1
Name:    www.xxx.yy
Address:  OLD.IP

Comment: @BlueCompute: Good point. It is not. XXX.YY resolves to THIS.DNS.SERVER.IP (XXX.YY is our company internal domain name) while www.XXX.YY resolves to OLD.IP. (Note: From the outside world, both www.XXX.YY and XXX.YY are resolved as NEW.IP.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local DNS server is configured with xxx.yy zone, and will never query public DNS servers. Just edit the www.xxx.yy record directly from DNS Manager.

Comment: There was a `WWW Host(A) OLD.IP static` record which I overlooked. After editing it, XXX.YY resolves to NEW.IP.